# How can I benefit from immutability when sharing data between threads?

Tags: c++, concurrency, immutability

I have heard that using immutable data types can make concurrent programming safer. (See, for example [this question](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/151733/if-immutable-objects-are-good-why-do-people-keep-creating-mutable-objects).) I am coding in C++ and trying to reap these benefits. But I am struggling to understand the concept.

If I create an immutable data type like so:

```
struct Immutable
{
public:
    const int x;

    Immutable(const int x)
    : x(x)
    {}
}
```

And I construct it on one thread, how can I consume it on another thread; i.e. I could do:

```
std::shared_ptr<Immutable> sharedMemory;

// Thread 1:
sharedMemory = std::make_shared<Immutable>(1);

// Thread 2:
DoSomething(*sharedMemory);
```

But I would still have to use locking or some kind of barriers to make this code thread safe because the value pointed to by sharedMemory may not be fully constructed when I try to access it on Thread 2.

How can I copy the immutable data between threads in a way that makes concurrency safer, as immutability is supposed to do?

Comment: I think the idea is to set up the shared object before starting the multiple threads.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
// Thread 1:
sharedMemory = std::make_shared<Immutable>(1);

// Thread 2:
DoSomething(*sharedMemory);
```

This is not an example of immutability.  The shared state of `sharedMemory` is *not* immutable.

Immutability would be two different threads both reading the `sharedMemory` constructed *before* either thread existed.

If they want to make changes to it, they *return* the changes.

Immutability means *all shared state cannot be altered*.  You can still pass data into a thread (via threading arguments), or pass data out of a thread (via a `future`)

You can even make isolated mutable shared state, like a queue of tasks for worker threads to consume.  Here the queue itself is mutable and carefully written.  The worker threads consume the tasks.

But the tasks only operate on immutable shared state, and they return data to other threads via the `future` that queuing the task returned.

---

A soft form of mutability is futures.

```
std::shared_future<std::shared_ptr<Immutable>> sharedMemory = create_shared_memory_async();

std::future<void> r = DoSomethingWithSharedMemoryAsync( sharedMemory );

// in DoSomethingWithSharedMemory
auto sharedMemoryV = sharedMemory.get(); // blocks until memory is ready
DoSomething(*sharedMemory);
```

This isn't fully immutable shared state.

---

Here is another impure use of immutable shared state:

```
cow_ptr<Document> ptr = GetCurrentDocument();

std::future<error_code> print = print_document_async(ptr);
std::future<error_code> backup = backup_document_async(ptr);

ptr.write().name = "new name";
```

a `cow_ptr` is a copy on write pointer.  It permits read-only immutable access.

If you want to change it, you call the `.write()` method.  If you are the only one owning that shared resource, it simply gives you write access.  Otherwise, it clones the resource and guarantees it is unique, then gives you write access.

Two different threads, the `print` and `backup` threads, have access to the `ptr`.  They cannot change any data that another thread can see (they are permitted to edit it, but that will only modify their local copy of the data).

Back in the main thread, we rename the document to a new name.  Neither the print nor backup threads will see this, as they have an immutable (logical) copy.

Two threads both accessing the same `ptr` variable is not legal, but they can access a *copy* of that `ptr` variable.

If the document itself was built out of `cow_ptr`s everywhere, a "copy" of the document would only copy the internal `cow_ptr`s; ie, it would atomic increment a few reference counts, not the entire state.

Modifying deep elements would involve breadcrumbs; you'd want a `breadcrumb_ptr` that keeps track of the route required to reach a given `cow_ptr`.  Then the `.write()` on it would proceed to duplicate everything back up to the root of the "document", possibly replacing each pointer (with a `.write()` call) as it goes.

Under this system, we have the ability to share extremely large and complex data structure shapeshots with O(1) cost between threads, and the only synchronization overhead being reference counting.

This still isn't pure immutability.  But in practice, this impure form of immutability gives many of the benefits, and permits you to efficiently and safely do things that are otherwise extremely dangerous or expensive.

Answer (score 0):

You only need synchronization on a variable if you have more than one thread and at least on of them will write to the variable.  With a immutable object you cannot write to it.  This means you can have as many threads as you want read from it with no ill effects since the data can never change.

So in this case you would either static initialize the object which is thread safe in C++11 and above or you would initialize it before the threads start and then share it with them.